# Kotlin Querydsl: cannot find javax.annotation.proceesing.Generated

Tags: spring-boot, maven, kotlin, querydsl

I am following this example https://felixzett.com/articles/minimal-maven-kotlin-querydsl-example/ to implement querydsl in a Springboot Kotlin Maven project. Using the pom mentioned, I managed to generate the q classes after running `mvn compile` and can run `mvn clean install` successfully as well, but when I try to run the project locally, I get error in all the q classes.

```
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Generated
  location: package javax.annotation.processing
```

I tried adding javax.annotation-api to the `<annotationProcessPaths>` element but it didn't work.

```
<annotationProcessorPath>
    <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</annotationProcessorPath>
```

I also tried adding it as a dependency, within that `<plugin>` element or in the main `<dependencies>` element, but these didn't work as well.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

May I know if anyone has any idea how to solve this?

**Update:**

I have both kotlin-maven-plugin and maven-compiler-plugin in my pom. I realise if I comment out the maven-compiler-plugin then the error is gone. But I am not sure if other parts of the app will be affected if it doesn't have this plugin.

Does anyone know if it is ok to just have the kotlin-maven-plugin, or how I should modify maven-compiler-plugin for the 2 plugins to work together?

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>compile</id>
            <phase>process-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>kapt</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>kapt</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sourceDirs>
                    <sourceDir>src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
                </sourceDirs>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <annotationProcessorPath>
                        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
                        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
                        <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
                        <classifier>jpa</classifier>
                    </annotationProcessorPath>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>test-compile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>test-compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sourceDirs>
                    <sourceDir>src/test/kotlin</sourceDir>
                    <sourceDir>target/generated-sources/kapt/test</sourceDir>
                </sourceDirs>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>

    <configuration>
        <args>
            <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
        </args>
        <compilerPlugins>
            <plugin>spring</plugin>
            <plugin>jpa</plugin>
            <plugin>all-open</plugin>
        </compilerPlugins>
        <pluginOptions>
            <option>all-open:annotation=javax.persistence.Entity</option>
            <option>all-open:annotation=javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass</option>
            <option>all-open:annotation=javax.persistence.Embeddable</option>
        </pluginOptions>
        <jvmTarget>1.8</jvmTarget>
    </configuration>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-noarg</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>none</phase>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <phase>none</phase>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>java-compile</id>
            <phase>process-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>java-test-compile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: For Java 8+ you're encouraged to use Querydsl 5.0.0.

Comment: @Jan-WillemGmeligMeyling I tried using querydsl 5.0.0 but still had the same error. I updated my question, could you help to take a look? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it is due to the Java version in the maven-compiler-plugin. After I changed it from 1.8 to 11, I do not get the error even if I have both kotlin-maven-plugin and maven-compiler-plugin.

```
<configuration>
    <source>1.8</source>
    <target>1.8</target>
</configuration>
```

Also change the java version to 11 in the `<properties>` element.

```
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code to apt-maven-plugin:

```
<options>
    <querydsl.generatedAnnotationClass>javax.annotation.Generated</querydsl.generatedAnnotationClass>
</options>
```

Something like:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.1.3</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>process</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
            <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
            <options>
        <querydsl.generatedAnnotationClass>javax.annotation.Generated</querydsl.generatedAnnotationClass>
        </options>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
```

Ref: https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/2799